# My 2.2" TFT LCD doesn't work (ILI9225 driver)(STM32F1)

Tags: c, lcd, stm32f10x, tft

Today I was working on this TFT LCD and I don't know why it doesn't work.

[image: figure1]

[image: figure2]

This LCD is a 2.2" TFT with ILI9225 LCD driver and is connected to my STM32F1. Here is the datasheet of LCD driver:

http://www.hpinfotech.ro/ILI9225B.pdf

And sample code:

http://www.displayfuture.com/Display/datasheet/controller/ILI9225.pdf

And here is other sources that I've read:

https://github.com/prenticedavid/TFT_SPI_kbv/blob/master/ILI9225_kbv.cpp
https://github.com/prenticedavid/TFT_SPI_kbv/blob/master/ILI9225_kbv.h

https://github.com/Nkawu/TFT_22_ILI9225/blob/master/src/TFT_22_ILI9225.h
https://github.com/Nkawu/TFT_22_ILI9225/blob/master/src/TFT_22_ILI9225.cpp

https://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/373581

**Software**

For sofware, here is the code I've used to initiate the LCD:

```
void TM_ILI9225_Init(void) 
  {


    ILI9225_RST_RESET;         
        TM_ILI9225_Delay(20000);  
    ILI9225_RST_SET;
        TM_ILI9225_Delay(200000);
    ILI9225_RST_RESET;
        TM_ILI9225_Delay(400000);   

    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x28);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x00CE);


    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x10);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0000);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x11);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0000);    
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x12);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0000);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x13);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0000);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x14);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0000);

    TM_ILI9225_Delay(400000);

    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x11);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x103B);//0x0018    
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x12);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x6121);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x13);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x006F);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x14);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x495F);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x10);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0A00);

    TM_ILI9225_Delay(400000);

    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x11);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x1000);

    TM_ILI9225_Delay(400000);

    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x01);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x011C);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x02);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0100);//0x0100
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x03);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x1030);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x07);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0000);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x08);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0808);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x0B);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x1100);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x0C);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0111);//0x0000
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x0F);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0F01);//
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x20);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0000);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x21);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0000);

    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x30);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0000);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x31);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x00DB);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x32);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0000);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x33);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0000);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x34);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x00DB);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x35);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0000);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x36);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x00AF);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x37);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0000);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x38);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x00DB);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x39);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0000);


    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x50);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0000);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x51);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0808);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x52);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x080A);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x53);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x000A);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x54);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0A08);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x55);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0808);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x56);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0000);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x57);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0A00);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x58);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0710);
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x59);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0710);

    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x07);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0012);

    TM_ILI9225_Delay(400000);

    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x07);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x1017);    


}
```

And here is functions:

```
void TM_ILI9225_Delay(volatile unsigned int delay) {
    for (; delay != 0; delay--); 
}

void TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(uint16_t data) {

    ILI9225_WRX_RESET;
    a = 3;
    while(a){
        a--;
    }
    GPIOA->BRR = GPIO_Pin_4;
    a = 3;
    while(a){
        a--;
    }
    SPI1->DR = data;
    a = 3;
    while(a){
        a--;
    }
    GPIOA->BSRR = GPIO_Pin_4; //setbit

}

void TM_ILI9225_SendData(uint16_t data) {

    ILI9225_WRX_SET;
    a = 3;
    while(a){
        a--;
    }
    GPIOA->BRR = GPIO_Pin_4;
    a = 3;
    while(a){
        a--;
    }
    SPI1->DR = data;
    a = 3;
    while(a){
        a--;
    }
    GPIOA->BSRR = GPIO_Pin_4;

}

void TM_ILI9225_SetCursorPosition(uint16_t x1, uint16_t y1) {
    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x20);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(x1);

    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x21);
    TM_ILI9225_SendData(y1);

}

void TM_ILI9225_Fill(uint16_t color) {
    unsigned int n, i, j;
    i = color >> 8;
    j = color & 0xFF;
    TM_ILI9225_SetCursorPosition(0, 0);

    TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x22);

    for (n = 0; n < ILI9225_PIXEL; n++) {
        TM_ILI9225_SendData(i);
        TM_ILI9225_SendData(j);
    }
```

And Macros:

```
#define ILI9225_RST_SET             GPIO_SetBits( GPIOA , GPIO_Pin_3)
#define ILI9225_RST_RESET           GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_3)
#define ILI9225_WRX_SET             GPIO_SetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_2)
#define ILI9225_WRX_RESET           GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_2)

#define ILI9225_WIDTH               220
#define ILI9225_HEIGHT              176
#define ILI9225_PIXEL                   38720
```

And this is the code that I use to change color of the LCD.

```
TM_ILI9225_Init();
TM_ILI9225_Fill(0xfb20);
```

I'm not going to put other parts of the code (such as SPI initialization and etc) because the rest of the code is tested and works very well.

**Hardware**

Here is the connection of the pins:

MCU  --------  LCD

PIN-3A ----> RST

PIN-2A ----> RS

NSS -------> CS

MOSI ------> SDI

CLK -------> CLK

3v3 -------> LED

Vcc -------> Vcc

GND -------> GND

I've checked the wiring by my logic analyzer and they works very well.

**What have I done so far?**

This LCD module has a 74HC245 IC and I thought it might be possible that this IC cannot handle high speed SPI then I reduced and increased the speed of the interface and checked it by my logic analyzer and nothing changed.
I manupulated the initialization code and especialy this part:

```
TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x0C);
TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0000);
```

To this:

```
TM_ILI9225_SendCommand(0x0C);
TM_ILI9225_SendData(0x0111);
```

But nothing happend. I think many codes on the net incorrectly used value `0x0000` for register `0x0c`.

Any idea would be appreciated

Comment: Yor delays will probably not work as intended. Also you should wait for any previous transfers to be completed before switching control lines (WRX, A4).

Comment: Your code is completely wrong. Almost everything important is wrong. Delays are wrong, communication is wrong - you for check if you can write something to DR, you do not wait for transmission to complete, but change the control lines. You do not cast DR writes to write correct data to DR. You need to rewrite it

Answer (score -2):

The display you showed in the photos is with the ILI9341 controller, not the ILI9225. Therefore, you can not run it with the 9225 initialization.